# Providing context to Firebase EventListener

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have setup a value event listener in Activity's onCreate method. In that method I am logging the data to console. I opened the activity and everything works fine. But if I close the activity and change the data, It still gets called and I can see that in logs.

So if I opened that activity say 5 times, on each update I see 5 logs messages.

Isn't there any solution where we can provide a context of that activity so the listeners die when the activity finishes.

```
rootRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Log.v(TAG, "Data Changed in Activity2");
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

I need to provide too many value listeners in RecyclerView also. It also causes multiple value changed event calls after it is scrolled. Because it is bind a new liestener at the existing position, and no reference to remove from the `onViewRecycled` method. So they are called multiple times and changes data randomly on screen.

Having context makes it easier to set value event listeners. Is there way I can keep track of all the listeners? There is also no method to get the listeners for a reference.

Comment: I have the same problem and ended up keeping a list of references to listeners with their context. When context is destroyed, I iterate through and remove all listeners for it. Terrible solution but it works.

Comment: Hi Greg, can you tell how you are keeping a list of references to listeners with their context? And how removing when context is destroyed?

Comment: Everywhere in the app where I add a firebase listener, I also store it in a ArrayList in an object along with the owning context/activity and the firebase query. When the activity is destroyed, I go through the list and call removeEventListener on the query. It's very fragile but I dont know what else to do.

Comment: Are you talking about this kind of a solution David mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33782474/1820644) ?

Comment: Yes I never saw that, but that is pretty much exactly what I'm doing

Comment: Thanks! Storing and removing listeners in every activity is mess.. There should be a better way to this..

Comment: Make sure to clean up your listeners in the opposite lifecycle event of where you attach them. So if you attach the listener in `onCreate()`, remove it in `onDestroy()`. Same for `onStart()`/`onStop()` and `onResume()`/`onPause()`.

Comment: Hi @Frank! Providing context would be a better thing to do. Would request you to add support for it..

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen how about providing a tag string when adding a listener, and then having ways to remove all listeners for a tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As there is currently no way to provide a context to listeners, need to keep track of all attached listeners and remove them as shown by David in the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33782474/1820644

---

For managing *value listeners* inside the `RecyclerView` I have came up with a solution that works well. I am using FirebaseUI's RecyclerView, but the solution should work on every `RecyclerView`.

**Step 1**: Firstly create a global `Map<String,ValueEventListener>` in your activity:

```
HashMap<String, ValueEventListener> mRecyclerViewFirebaseListeners = new HashMap<>();
```

**Step 2**: Bind `ValueEventListener` in `populateViewHolder` (in firebaseUI) or `onBindViewHodler` and add it to our map `mRecyclerViewFirebaseListeners`. Also, attach a `Tag` to view holder with the value of our **key**

```
protected void populateViewHolder(final ViewHolder viewHolder,
                                  Boolean model, int position) {

    Log.v(TAG, "Populating viewHolder for position: " + position);

    // Get the key and add listener
    String key = this.getRef(position).getKey();
    ValueEventListener listener = mRootRef.child("events").child(key)
            .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    Log.v(TAG, "Event Data Change");
                    // ...
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    Log.v(TAG, databaseError.getMessage());
                }
            });

    Log.v(TAG, "Listener set for event key: " + key + " (position: " +
            position + ")");

    // Add to our map and set tag on view holder
    mRecyclerViewFirebaseListeners.put(key, listener);
    viewHolder.itemView.setTag(R.id.TAG_RCV_EVENT_KEY, key);
    Log.d(TAG, "Added tag for position:" + position);

    // do other work here

}
```

**Step 3**: Remove a listener for the view holder when a view is recycled.

```
@Override
public void onViewRecycled(ViewHolder holder) {
    super.onViewRecycled(holder);

    // Get key from the view holder
    String key = (String) holder.itemView.getTag(R.id.TAG_RCV_EVENT_KEY);
    Log.v(TAG, "Recycling view set for key: " + key);

    // Remove listener for the retrieved key and also remove it from our map
    mRootRef.child("events").child(key)
            .removeEventListener(mRecyclerViewFirebaseListeners.get(key));
    mRecyclerViewFirebaseListeners.remove(key);
    Log.v(TAG, "On View Recycled, Removed Event listener for key: " + key);

    // ...

}
```

**Step 4**: Remove remaining listeners in `onDestroy()`

```
@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();

    // Iterate over map and remove listeners for the key
    for (Map.Entry<String, ValueEventListener> entry : mRecyclerViewFirebaseListeners.entrySet()) {
        String key = entry.getKey();
        ValueEventListener value = entry.getValue();
        mRootRef.child("events").child(key).removeEventListener(value);
        Log.v(TAG, "Removed Event listener for key: " + key);
    }
}
```

This will remove all your listeners from recycler view.

If you have more value listeners other than recyclerview, use a new map for those others all combine it in this map if it matches the key pattern for the same path.

Alternatively you can put a full path instead of just a key as the key of a Map. Like in example we have used value of 'key' under the child **events** as the key of a Map, but you can put `events/<key>` as the key of a Map and remove in one go in `onDestroy` with `mRootRef.child("<your_combined_key_from_map>").removeListener(listener)`.

Hope this helps someone.