# Is there a way in Android Firebase to get a list of all attached listener

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I create a standard listener like this

```
private ValueEventListener aListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    };
```

And attached to my Firebase databas

```
databaseRef.child(chatRoot)
                .orderByChild("some key")
                .limitToLast(12)
                .addValueEventListener(aListener );
```

If I now have 5-10 different listener I wanted a way to peek in and see how many there are attached. Lets say I want to do this to insure listener are on/off

Comment: Check out this answer, which suggests using a hashmap to keep track of listeners, where the key is the database reference and the value is the listener: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33782474/4816918

Comment: Thanks actually I am doing exactly that right now with hashmap. Just asking this question anyway to kind of shake the tree